# Any harm if JSESSIONID Exposed in HTTP?

Tags: oracle, cookies, weblogic, single-sign-on, jsessionid

Just curious, it is possible to launch an impersonate attack by using JSESSIONID if the JSESSIONID cookies is exposed in HTTP communication channel despite the Auth Cookie is already enabled?

Is the weblogic allow on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Auth Cookie is enabled  causes the WebLogic Server to send a new secure cookie, _WL_AUTHCOOKIE_JSESSIONID, to the browser when authenticating via an **HTTPS** connection.

If you have just HTTP you will have only the JSESSIONID which is not a secure cookie

worth checking [Can someone who merely knows my current JSESSIONID impersonate / hijack my session (Tomcat 7/Glassfish 3.2))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476439/can-someone-who-merely-knows-my-current-jsessionid-impersonate-hijack-my-sessi)

So the answer is yes.